# How can I implement an error-free dynamic in-line style in react with typescript?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, inline-styles

Even though the code works, the following problem is shown by typescript:

```
Type '{ flexDirection: string; justifyContent: string; alignItems: string; marginLeft: string; minHeight: string; } | null' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties | undefined'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties | undefined'.ts(2322)
```

What I want to do is flexibly change the style of an element based on a boolean prop:

```
<nav style={refs.vertical === true ? verticalStyle : null} className={styles.navWrapper}>
```

And "verticalStyle" is defined as the following:

```
  const verticalStyle = {flexDirection: 'column',
  justifyContent:'space-evenly',
  alignItems: 'flex-start',
  marginLeft: '2rem',
  minHeight: 'inherit'
}
```

Since the code runs perfectly fine (and did so earlier in the pure JS version), I wonder why TS struggles with recognizing that I am, in fact, passing valid CSS properties. Apart from silencing the error, is there any way to solve this elegantly and error-free?

Comment: change `null` to `undefined` in the `style` ternary operation

Comment: I did so, but this alone was not sufficient. TS still does not accept the first part of the ternary expression as  "CSS properties"

Comment: I think I now whats going on. Can you declare `verticalStyle` with the type `Partial<CSSProperties>`? Or you can also put `as const` behind the variable declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning `null`, return an empty `object` or `undefined` since the Type is `CSSProperties | undefined`.

```
<nav style={refs.vertical === true ? verticalStyle : {}} className={styles.navWrapper}>
```

or

```
<nav style={refs.vertical === true ? verticalStyle : undefined} className={styles.navWrapper}>
```

Comment: I did as you told me but the error persists. TS does not accept the first part of the ternary operator: 
Type '{ flexDirection: string; justifyContent: string; alignItems: string; marginLeft: string; minHeight: string; } | undefined' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties | undefined'.

Comment: If it will work for you i will add it to my answer

Comment: You need to explicitly say that the verticalStyle is CSSpropeties. `const verticalStyle: CSSpropeties`

Answer (score 0):

So after quite some searching, I finally found the answer. Basically, it is not possible to pass the style as a variable in Typescript. Instead, the style has to be applied directly inline. I couldn't find out exactly why that is, but here's the solution:

```
<nav style={refs.vertical === true ? {
      flexDirection: 'column',
      justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
      alignItems: 'flex-start',
      marginLeft: '2rem',
      minHeight: 'inherit'
    }
      : undefined}
```